# Event tracking within PHP code

Tags: php, input, event-tracking, submit-button

I'm trying to implement event tracking to a submit button on a contact form. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<input type='button' value='".((get_theme_option("translator_status") == "enable") ?   get_text("tranlator_send_message") : __('Send comment','theme_localization'))."' id='submit2' class='feedback_go' name='submit'>
```

And here is the code I need to place within it:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact Us Form', 'Submit', 'Submit']);"
```

The double quote marks at the beginning and end in the code are causing a server error. If I use single quotes instead, the tracking doesn't work.

I've tried wrapping the double quotes in single but that causes a server error too.

I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong and a workaround.

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, `"tranlator_send_message"` has a typo. No idea if that pertains to the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) you can make this code a bit easier to manage:

```
echo sprintf('<input type="button" id="submit2" class="feedback_go" value="%s" onclick="_gaq.push(%s);" />',
    htmlspecialchars(get_theme_option("translator_status") == "enable" ? get_text("tranlator_send_message") : __('Send comment','theme_localization'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
    json_encode(array('_trackEvent', 'Contact Us Form', 'Submit', 'Submit'))
);
```

It also uses `htmlspecialchars()` to escape the contents of either `get_text()` or `__()` properly.